# Access Ubuntu formatted HDD as external USB drive from MAC

Tags: macos, ubuntu, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I am having one HDD in which Ubuntu was installed, now that system is not working properly and I wan't to use that HDD as external HDD with my MacBook Pro installed OS X Yosemite.

I have HDD Case to make it as USB Drive.

Now when I connect this HDD using USB to my MacBook Pro It is showing me one message

"The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer." with three buttons "Initialize", "Ignore" and "Eject".

When I click on "Initialize" it opens Disk Utility and shows HDD as unmounted.

Any one have any idea how can I mount my Ubuntu system HDD as external drive to my OS X Yosemite?

Comment: What format? ExtFS will need 3rd party support afaik, something like [Paragon ExtFS](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/)

Comment: if its formatting as ext4 for example you will likely need to use OSX Fuse... http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin Paragon ExtFS worked for me. Though i used only trial version as my goal is just to get data from ExtFS formatted HDD.